# How to draw this smart diagram?

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics, diagrams, tikz-styles, smartdiagram

I am drawing a diagram having three major steps say A,B,C. I figured out that Smartdiagram gave a neater look(also colorful),than using Tikz.

```
\smartdiagram[circular diagram:clockwise]{A,B,C}
```

How can I add text,more arrows to the image such as given in the attached image? Is that even supported,while using smart diagram package?
[image]

Comment: Since Smartdiagram uses tikz, you can probably use tinngs like \node[midway], depending on just how dumbed down the interface is.

Comment: There is limited support for such things through the `additions` library, see section 3 of the manual.

Comment: If anybody wants to provide answers, kindly answer as a separate post, not as a comment. So I can accept your answers..and other people will also be able to vote.

Comment: The `smartdiagram` manual does not provide any example that has additional test available, as you need it. You would probably be better off creating the whole thing in `tikz` directly. There is nothing in `smartdiagram` that is not done with `tikz` as far as I can see...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As Torbjørn pointed, there is limited support for add items (modules in manual jargon) through the `additions` library and the  `\smartdiagramadd` command. The main problem is that you can  set only some global  options for the added items.

This mean that individually you can control only   the relative positions with respect main items (not with respect arrows) and in some extent the style of connection (basically, right, left or bidirectional arrows with/without head/tails, or none), but unlike show your image, you cannot set (as far I know) additional items with more than one type of font color, for instance.  A minimal example of what you can / cannot obtain:

[image: mwe]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{smartdiagram}
\usesmartdiagramlibrary{additions}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}

\begin{document}

\smartdiagramset{border color=none,
uniform color list=teal!70!black for 3 items,
module shape= ellipse, 
module minimum height=2.5cm,
circular distance=4cm,
font=\Huge\sffamily\bfseries, 
text width=5em,
text color=white,
arrow line width=8pt,
additions={
additional item font=\sffamily\bfseries\color{red!50},
additional item offset=3em,
additional item height=0em,
additional item text width=5em,
additional arrow color=teal!40,
additional arrow line width=4pt,
}}

\smartdiagramadd[circular diagram:clockwise]{B,C,A}{
right of module1/Text 1 without arrow, 
above of module1/Text 2,
left of module3/Text 3,
above left of module3/Text 4,
below left of module2/{Something}}
\smartdiagramconnect{-}{module1/additional-module2}
\smartdiagramconnect{<-}{module3/additional-module3}
\smartdiagramconnect{<->}{module3/additional-module4}
\smartdiagramconnect{->}{module2/additional-module5}

\end{document}
```